# DateTime.ParseExact with 7 digits / one or two digit month

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

Until now i thought that i would understand how `DateTime.ParseExact` works, but this is confusing. Why does following line returns `false`?

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("2013122", "yyyyMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out lastUpdate)
```

The month can also have two digits. In my opinion it should be able to understand that it means 22 January 2013. Why i'm on the wrong track? Did I miss something or is there an easy workaround?

---

Meanwhile i'm using this workaround which is not very elegant but works:

```
public static DateTime? ParseDate_yyyyMdd(String date)
{
    if (date == null)
        return null;
    date = date.Trim();
    if (date.Length < 7)
        return null;
    if (date.Length == 7)
        date = date.Insert(4, "0");
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        return dt;
    return null;
}
```

Gives my desired result:

```
DateTime? date = ParseDate_yyyyMdd("2013122");
Console.Write(date.ToString()); // 01/22/2013
```

However, i'm still interested in the reason for this limitation. Maybe someone also has a better approach.

Comment: I think the answers are correct but this still seems bizarre to me. I don't understand the _widest_ rule. You are saying _hey, try to parse my first 4 character as a year, after 1 character as a month, after 2 character as a day_. but method ignores it.

Comment: .. And it says: `hey, your string doesn't have date separator, and that's why I ignore your format because it doesn't have widest form of your specifiers`.

Comment: If you use `""yyyyMd"` instead, it parses, but with the wrong interpretation, `lastUpdate`=2013/Dec/2.

Comment: Your workaround can be a bit less ugly: `if (date.Length == 7)
               { date = date.Insert(4, "0"); }`

Comment: I connected to .NET Framework Team about this issue, and [here their response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26778076/447156).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If you do not use date or time separators in a custom format pattern, use the invariant culture for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form, "H".

I think that the reason is that it tries to parse left to right (without backtracking). Because there are no delimiters, it can't determine the boundaries of the date parts.

Comment: Have you tried to convert it like so? It still returns false for `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: @OndrejJanacek It returns `true` with `yyyyMMd`. Your format is requires 8 character which string is 7 character.

Comment: @Soner Gönül But it's not parsed as expected

Comment: @Plue It is actually. With `yyyyMMd` format you get `02.12.2013` (2 december 2013). Ondrej's format doesn't parsing any of them because it is not the same lenght at least with `"2013122"`

Comment: @Soner Gönül So how do you obtain **22.01.2013** from **2013122**?

Comment: @Plue I don't know. That's why this is a good question. I just want to point Ondrej's format doesn't match the lenght of the string.

Comment: @SonerGönül I just pointed out that merely doubling a letter as the answers says is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

I did track down that in source code. Which confirms the answers of flipchart and Mark Sturgill.

Somewhere an internal ParseByFormat is called which counts (in your case) the 'M':

```
    // System.DateTimeParse
    private static bool ParseByFormat(ref __DTString str, ref __DTString format, ref ParsingInfo parseInfo, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, ref DateTimeResult result)
    {   
        ...
        case 'M':
            num = format.GetRepeatCount();
            if (num <= 2)
            {
                if (!DateTimeParse.ParseDigits(ref str, num, out newValue2) && (!parseInfo.fCustomNumberParser || !parseInfo.parseNumberDelegate(ref str, num, out newValue2)))
                {
                    result.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind.Format, "Format_BadDateTime", null);
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

The next call is not very interesting, except for the 2 little numbers in ParseDigits call:

```
    // System.DateTimeParse
    internal static bool ParseDigits(ref __DTString str, int digitLen, out int result)
    {
        if (digitLen == 1)
        {
            return DateTimeParse.ParseDigits(ref str, 1, 2, out result);
        }
        return DateTimeParse.ParseDigits(ref str, digitLen, digitLen, out result);
    }
```

But now we get to the fun part:

```
    // System.DateTimeParse
    internal static bool ParseDigits(ref __DTString str, int minDigitLen, int maxDigitLen, out int result)
    {
        result = 0;
        int index = str.Index;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < maxDigitLen; i++)
        {
            if (!str.GetNextDigit())
            {
                str.Index--;
                break;
            }
            result = result * 10 + str.GetDigit();
        }
        if (i < minDigitLen)
        {
            str.Index = index;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So that means (as already answered):

If you do not use the maximum number of digits AND the next character is also a digit, the format is not valid. Which is the reason why the following returns true:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("20131-22", "yyyyM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out lastUpdate)
```

Don't ask me about the reasons for that limitation - it is just there in source code.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was just looking through the source :D

Comment: +1 Thanks for the analysis.  But it should have been   mentioned also in the documentation more explicitly. I hope this will be fixed sometime.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx

> If you do not use date or time separators in a custom format pattern, use the invariant culture for the provider parameter and **the widest form of each custom format specifier**. For example, if you want to specify hours in the pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form, "H".