# TimeSpan.ParseExact does not recognize input format

Tags: c#, .net, time-format

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but I can't seem to find an answer for mine.

I have this line of C# code:

```
var x = TimeSpan.ParseExact("800", "hmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And it throws an exception saying that the input format was invalid. If I put "0800" and "hhmm", it works. I've seen people use the single "h" in TimeSpan-Conversions, so it has to be possible to do so. There are also no special letters  that would need to be escaped.

I tried using CurrentCulture instead of InvariantCulture, but that didn't change anything. Right now, I'm padding my strings to have 0s on the left side, but I would like to know, why the TimeSpan-Parsing failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm don't know  why that is so or where it is documented, but three digit timespans seem not to be supported in `TimeSpan.ParseExact`. So you could workaround it by padding it with leading zeros:

```
string ts = "800";
var x = TimeSpan.ParseExact(ts.PadLeft(4, '0'), "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I guess that the reason why `TimeSpan` cannot parse this is related to the reason why [`DateTime.ParseExact` cannot parse 7 digits with one or two digit month and without a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902722/datetime-parseexact-with-7-digits-one-or-two-digit-month).

Comment: @Manuel Hoffmann: _"Right now, I'm padding my strings to have 0s on the left side"_ whoops, until now i haven't seen that this is already your workaround. Maybe my last sentence has some added value.

Comment: You're right, I already do that. What an odd behaviour on C#'s side.